# showing product outofstock in php basic inventory project

Tags: php, inventory-management

hey i am trying to make a basic inventory project in which i want to show message of out of stock on sell product button. basically in database if the balance_quantity is 0 then the entry should stop and display a message. tried with defining variable $balance_quantity = "0"; and also 
substituting if and elseif 
here's my code.

```
<?php 

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'inventory');

    if (isset($_GET['sell'])) {
        $item_id = $_GET['sell'];
        $balance_quantity = $_GET['bal']-1;

        $record = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE item_master SET balance_quantity=$balance_quantity WHERE item_id=$item_id");

    }

    if(isset($_GET['buy'])) {
        $item_id = $_GET['buy'];


        $quantity =  1;
        $query =  "INSERT INTO transaction (Item_id, quantity) VALUES ($item_id,$quantity)" ;
        mysqli_query($db, $query);  
    }

?>


<td>
    <a href="cart.php?sell=<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>&bal=<?php echo $row['balance_quantity']; ?>" class="btn">Sell</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="cart.php?buy=<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>" class="btn">Buy</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Just select "balance_quantity" and check if it's > 0. Also you should never use a query like this because it's vulnerable to SQL injections. Take a look at [prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: sure will keep that in mind, and did checked with > 0 but gives the same output ($msg), even if balance_quantity table has value greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: make something that gets the current balance from the DB and compare them.

Here, you are getting the balance from a GET value. What if another user buys or sells at the same time?

Example:

```
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'inventory');

    if (isset($_GET['sell'])) {
        $item_id = $_GET['sell'];
        $balance_query= mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT balance_quantity FROM item_master WHERE item_id=$item_id"));

$balance_quantity = balance_query['balance_quantity'];

//Rest of logic. Or even better, make a function that plain returns getBalance($itemId)

    }
```